# React ref called multiple times

Tags: reactjs

Having such simple `React` (with the `react-hook-form` library) *form*

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const firstNameRef1 = useRef(null);
  const onSubmit = data => { 
    console.log("...onSubmit")
  };
  const { ref, ...rest } = register('firstName', {
    required: " is required!",
    minLength: {
      value: 5,
      message: "min length is <5"
    }
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <hr/>
      <input {...rest} name="firstName" ref={(e) => {
        console.log("...ref")
        ref(e)
        firstNameRef1.current = e // you can still assign to ref
      }} />
      {errors.firstName && <span>This field is required!</span>}

      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

I'm getting:

```
...ref 
...ref 
...onSubmit 
...ref 
...ref
```

in the console output after the *Submit* button click.

My question is why is there so many `...ref` re-calls? Should't it just be the one and only `ref` call at all?

P.S.
When I've removed the `formState: { errors }` from the `useForm` destructuring line above the problem disappears - I'm getting only one `...ref` in the console output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why is there so many ...ref re-calls?

This is happening because every time you render, you are creating a new function and passing it into the ref. It may have the same text as the previous function, but it's a new function. React sees this, assumes something has changed, and so calls your new function with the element.

Most of the time, getting ref callbacks on every render makes little difference. Ref callbacks tend to be pretty light-weight, just assigning to a variable. So unless it's causing you problems, i'd just leave it. But if you do need to reduce the callbacks, you can use a memoized function:

```
const example = useCallback((e) => {
  console.log("...ref")
  ref(e);
  firstNameRef1.current = e
}, [])

// ...
<input {...rest} name="firstName" ref={example} />
```

Comment: Thx for Your answer BUT can You please explain me WHY does removing the `formState: { errors }` from the `useForm ` destructuring line resolves the multiple `ref` calls

Comment: I don't know. Presumably that's resulting in the component rendering fewer times, but i don't see how a change to destructuring would result in fewer renders.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are calling `ref(e)` in your `input` tag. That's why it is calling it repeatedly. Try removing if from the `function` and then try again.

```
<input {...rest} name="firstName" ref={(e) => {
  console.log("...ref")
  ref(e)  // <-- ****Remove this line of code*****
  firstNameRef1.current = e // you can still assign to ref
}} />
```